# Will MtGox accept a poor quality ID photo?

Tags: exchanges, mtgox, identity

An exchange I use (Mt. Gox) wants me to send a color scan of my ID.  The only camera I have access to is a grainy camera on my feature phone.  I don't know the camera resolution but it is not very high.

The ID is readable but doesn't fill even half the image.  If I try to get closer, the image is too out of focus.

Will this image be accepted or will my account end up getting locked ("under review") until I send in a scan with a better photo?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but do you have a webcam?  That may be able to take reasonable quality photos.

Comment: @ChrisMoore Figured out another option -- a friend with a better phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not. The information on the scanned image must be very clear and show a clear photograph.

It is best to scan the ID using a quality scanner. Even a picture taken on a smartphone and filtered with a "scanning" program was insufficient for their requirements.

Source: I lazily tried everything, getting rejected each time, then finally going and scanning the ID.

Comment: side-note: with Bitcoin-Central I just took a picture with my smartphone and they accepted it, but it was an (relatively) high-quality phone camera.